# Current best practice for compiling pixel shaders in WPF?

Tags: wpf, directx, shader, hlsl

I'd like to color some icons in a WPF application using a pixel shader. However, when I go to get the DirectX SDK to get fxc, I see that it's deprecated -- I find links to DirectX11 and the new "Effects" system in WPF. However, that seems to be deprecated as well.

I'm wondering: what is the current practice to get a pixel shader into WPF? For context (though this shouldn't matter technically), I'm using a Prism/Unity-based MVVM architecture, so I'd like to eventually handle these colors through XAML binding.

I see alot of people using SlimDX, but I'd really like to avoid introducing yet another library dependency into my application.

Comment: Are you looking for fxc for newer versions of DirectX? It's now a part of the Windwos SDK instead of a separate DirectX SDK [(source)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: This actually is all I was missing. If you would like to submit this as an answer I would be happy to approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DirectX SDK was merged into the Windows SDK back when Windows 8 was released [[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx)], which is where you can find the newer versions of FXC.

Comment: See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) and this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/). With VS 2012, VS 2013, or VS 2015 you already have the HLSL compiler ``FXC.EXE``.

Comment: Depending of your needs, it may be interesting to write your own shader compiler tool. FXC.EXE is only a frontend for what you have in `d3dcompiler.h`. Running a single process that trigger shader compile on several thread or even distribute them over a network can be handy. Plus you get control over logging errors, caching and file handling.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a few hours to get find a solution so i wanted to share it:

Visual Studio:
Add below batch script to Project(right click Project in the Solution Explorer Window)>Properties>BuildEvents>"**Pre-build event command line:**"-field) and adapt the path.

```
echo COMPILING SHADERS:
set Compiler=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86\fxc.exe
set OutputFile=$(ProjectDir)Resources\SearchColorFilter.ps
set InputFile=$(ProjectDir)Resources\SearchColorFilter.fx

"%Compiler%" /O0 /Fc /Zi /T ps_2_0 /Fo "%OutputFile%" "%InputFile%"
```

here is an Example of a pixel shader, it replaces magenta-like colors with white, keeps yellow and greys out the rest

SearchColorFilter.ps:

```
sampler2D implicitInputSampler : register(S0);
float filterControl : register(C0);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR{
    float4 color = tex2D(implicitInputSampler, uv);

    if (filterControl == 1) {

        //modify magenta tint into white, Magenta: float4(1,0,1,1)
        if (color.r > 0.35 && color.g < 0.2 && color.b > 0.35) return float4(color.r, color.r * 0.5 + color.b * 0.5, color.b, 1);//MAGENTA-->WHITE

        //keep yellow, Yellow: float4(1,0,1,1)
        if (color.r > 0.35 && color.g > 0.35 && color.b < 0.2) return color;//YELLOW-->YELLOW

        //grey out rest
        return float4(color.r * 0.5, color.g * 0.5, color.b * 0.5, color.a);//OTHER -> HALF VALUE (= grey out)
    }
    return color;

}
```

**Don't forget** to:

- add the created .ps-file to your project via the Solution Explorer and set its Build Action to "Resource"
- save the .fx file with correct Encoding: "US-ASCII - Codepage 20127"

BONUS:
In order to apply a shader to an UIElement, this can be done by creating a class

SearchColorFilter.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Effects;

public class SearchColorFilter : ShaderEffect
{
    static SearchColorFilter()
    {
        var uri = MakePackUri("Resources/SearchColorFilter.ps");
        _pixelShader.UriSource = uri;
    }

    private static PixelShader _pixelShader = new PixelShader();

    public SearchColorFilter()
    {
        this.PixelShader = _pixelShader;
        UpdateShaderValue(InputProperty);
        UpdateShaderValue(FilterControlProperty);
    }

    public Brush Input
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(InputProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InputProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly System.Windows.DependencyProperty InputProperty =
        ShaderEffect.RegisterPixelShaderSamplerProperty("Input", typeof(SearchColorFilter), 0);

    public double FilterControl
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FilterControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterControlProperty, value); }
    }

    public static System.Uri MakePackUri(string relativeFile)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly a = typeof(SearchColorFilter).Assembly;
        string assemblyShortName = a.ToString().Split(',')[0];
        string uriString = "pack://application:,,,/" + assemblyShortName + ";component/" + relativeFile;
        return new System.Uri(uriString);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FilterControl", typeof(double), typeof(SearchColorFilter),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0d, PixelShaderConstantCallback(0)));
}
```

Now you can assign the shader to any UIElement using

```
SearchColorFilter recolorShader = new SearchColorFilter();
recolorShader.FilterControl = 1;
MyUIElement.Effect = recolorShader;
```